# compiler options to increase optimization performance of the code

Tags: gcc, g++, arm, cross-compiling, intel

I am porting the code from INTEL architecture to ARM architecture. The same code I am trying to build with arm cross compilers on centos. Are there any compiler options that increase the performance of executable image because the image on INTEL might not give similar performance on ARM. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of optimization options exist in GCC. By default the compiler tries to make the compilation process as short as possible and produce an object code that makes debugging easy. However, gcc also provides several options for optimization.

Four general levels of incremental optimizations for performance are available in GCC and can be activated by passing one of the options `-O0`, `-O1`, `-O2` or `-O3`. Each of these levels activates a set of optimizations that can be also activated manually by specifying the corresponding command line option. For instance with `-O1` the compiler performs branches using the *decrement and branch* instruction (if available and applicable) rather then decrementing the register, comparing it to zero and branching in separate instructions. This *decrement and branch* can be also specified manually by passing the `-fbranch-count-reg` option. Consider that optimizations performed at each level also depend on the target architecture, you can get the list of available and enabled optimization by running GCC with the `-Q --help=optimizers` option.

Generally speaking the levels of optimization correspond to (notice that at each level also the optimization of the previous ones are applied):

- `-O0`: the default level, the compiler tries to reduce compilation time and produce an object code that can be easily processed by a debugger
- `-O1`: the compiler tries to reduce both code size and execution time. Only optimizations that do not take a lot of compile time are performed. Compilation may take considerably more memory.
- `-O2`: the compiler applies almost all optimizations available that do not affect the code size. Compiling takes more but performance should improve.
- `-O3`: the compiler applies also optimization that might increase the code size (for instance inlining functions)

For a detailed description of all optimization options you can have a look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).
As a general remark consider that compiler optimization are designed to work in the general case but their effectiveness will depend a lot on both you program and the architecture you are running it on.

Edit:
If you are interested in memory paging optimization there is the `-freorder-blocks-and-partition` option (activated also with `-O2`). This option reorders basic blocks inside each function to partition them in *hot blocks* (called frequently) and *cold blocks* (called rarely). *Hot blocks* are then placed in contiguous memory locations. This should increasing cache locality and paging performance.

Comment: thank you for ur suggestion i have used O0 optimization level and compiled my code. My actual doubt was to know about the compiler option that optimizes the memory pages usage at the run time. I will go through the link u shared

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my post to add some information on memory paging optimization. Please consider voting/accepting the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: thanks alot @mziccard.. that's the option I needed.. I am unable to upvote this because i have reputation less than 15 :)

Comment: Happy to help! Very few people care/mind about compiler optimizations but they can really make the difference. And also make your life a nightmare if you are debugging :)

Comment: `-O0` code is likely to perform very badly compared to what will be produced at `-O1`. If you have a recent version of GCC `-Og` will perform some optimisation while trying to preserve the debugging experience. For most applications, you probably want to use `-O2` almost always.